# Laravel 5.6 API Routes error 404

Tags: laravel-5

My api routes are returning a 404 error no matter how I set them up in my routes/api.php. This worked like a charm pre-5.6. What happened? Am I missing something after setting up the vanilla application?

Edit: Here is my routes/api.php

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    Route::get('/api/members', function (Request $request) {
        // code to get members
    });

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
```

Hitting http://www.mysite.loc/api/members yields a 404 screen in Laravel and in Postman. What's odd is this route works just fine if I put it in my routes/web.php file.

Comment: Show us your `routes/api.php` file

Comment: File has been added.

Comment: @JasonAyer You don't need to add '/api/members' 'api ' is added by default in all the routes defined in api.php. just add Route::get('/members', function (Request $request) {
        // code to get members
    });

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeZilla Could you add that as an answer, so that _Jason Ayer_ can mark the question as closed, please?

Comment: @Toothbrush added the answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers if you mark _CodeZilla_’s answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `/api/members` `api` is added by default in all the routes defined in api.php.

From official documentation:

> Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route group by the RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply it to every route in the file. You may modify the prefix and other route group options by modifying your RouteServiceProvider class.

For documentation [check.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

just add

`Route::get('/members', function (Request $request) { 
    // code to get members 
});`